# Nested generic parameters of a generic class' object don't make sense

Tags: java, generics

The type `Class<T>` is has one generic parameter, namely the type of that class an object represents, which makes perfect sense.

However, when working with the class object of a type that has generic parameters itself, e.g. `List<T>`, we can handle that in two possible ways:

1. We refer to that as `Class<List<MyType>>`, which doesn't make sense: The generic parameter of `List` loses its meaning since we just refer to its (static) class. Even `Class<List<?>>` looks conceptually wrong to me.
2. We just leave out the inner parameter and refer to it as `Class<List>`. But in this case, the compiler will generate a warning, since it detects `List` as non-parameterized.

First I thought, that compilers are not smart enough to handle this case correctly, but I guess the original reason has a conceptual nature.

Is there a clean solution for this problem? If not, what would be the best handling in your opinion? Inserting a `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` or using `Class<List<?>>`?

**Update**

I'm facing this problem on some code where the user should be able to provide a custom class for a database connection. This class should extend `DoodleDatabaseMap<T>`, which is an abstract class and implements `Map<String, T>`.

I think above description isn't precise enough. It gets hairy when I need to save pass class objects or assign them to a variable. My API method looks as follows:

```
public static void setDatabaseMap(Class<? extends DoodleDatabaseMap> databaseMap) {
    // ...
}
```

Giving a generic type to `DoodleDatabaseMap` here will cause a compile error when calling it (`FileDatabaseMap` extends `DoodleDatabaseMap`):

```
DoodleDebug.setDatabaseMap(FileDatabaseMap.class);
```

This causes an error message: `The method setDatabaseMap(Class<? extends DoodleDatabaseMap<?>>) in the type DoodleDebug is not applicable for the arguments (Class<FileDatabaseMap>)`

Comment: Provide a specific piece of code where you need to use one of these approaches. I don't see any problem when using `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` properly.

Comment: `Is there a clean solution for this problem?` => this implies there is a problem, but I fail to see it. There is nothing wrong with `Class<List<?>>`.

Comment: I updated the answer (twice). I had forgotten to highlight one problem with the generic type wildcard.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach [Producer Extends, Consumer Super](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/2970947).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Does that refer to the error message? You see that `FileDatabaseMap` actually extends `DoodleDatabaseMap`, right?

Answer (score 2):

> This class should extend DoodleDatabaseMap, which is an abstract class and implements Map

Then you could change this

```
static void setDatabaseMap(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") 
    Class<DoodleDatabaseMap> databaseMap)
```

to use the [wildcard capture-of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) type like

```
static void setDatabaseMap(Class<DoodleDatabaseMap<?>> databaseMap)
```